# How to create array of objects of ES6 class while calling constructor of this class?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6

I would like to create array or object of objects while calling constructor of class? I mean, everytime I'm calling class constructor it adds new object to array or object.

f.e.

```
let blocks = {};

class Block(){

    constructor(X,Y,width,height){
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        ...
        and now I would like to add this created object to "blocks"
        something like: blocks.push(and this object here)
    }
}
```

How can I implement something like this? Or should it be another function?

Comment: You can add another method inside class and call this metod in constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> something like: blocks.push(and this object here)

That's exactly how you'd do it, but `blocks` should be an array, not an object. So:

```
let blocks = [];
```

and then in the constructor:

```
blocks.push(this);
```

Live Example:

```js
let blocks = []; // <== [], not {}

class Block {    // No ()

    constructor(X,Y,width,height){
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        blocks.push(this);
    }
}

new Block(1, 1, 1, 1);
new Block(2, 2, 2, 2);
new Block(3, 3, 3, 3);

console.log(blocks.length); // 3
```

**But**, beware that that means the object (the block that was created) will always be retained in memory, even if whatever created it originally finishes with it and lets it go. Normally, you wouldn't have a constructor do something like this, you'd leave it to the caller.

Depending on why you're building this list of blocks, you may (or may not) want to use [`WeakSet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) or [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) instead.

Comment: And concerning the WeakSet/Maps: they are not really useful as one cannot iterate them

Comment: OMG.. Literally I spend at least half an hour to try to implement it. And I didn't think about simple "this". Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms - Well again, that depends on what the use case is. Traditional use of `WeakMap` is private per-instance information, so you don't need iteration. I've never actually needed a `WeakSet`, but I've heard there are use cases for it. ;-)

Comment: @JonasWilms yeah, I'm using WeakMaps but I got getters and setters so it shouldn't be problem, right?

Comment: @WojciechJakubek - Not sure how getters/setters would relate to using a `WeakMap` (for or against). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean, just getters, cause I need this array of objects to draw blocks then on canvas

Comment: @wojciech `blocks[0]` is not a getter, thats just a property access. Getters / setters are a completely different thing, just as Maps / Sets, so please just stick to the terms you already worked with, otherwise that just creates confusion :)

Comment: @WojciechJakubek - If your goal is to have a list of blocks to draw on a canvas, I recommend **not** having the `Block` constructor add the block to the list. Have the code calling the constructor do it. Make that code responsible for adding to (and possibly removing from) the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your cannot the `push` method because it is not present on an object. Currently your created an object by:

```
let blocks = [];  // creates object with literal syntax.
```

`push` is a method which is only available on arrays:

```js
let obj = {};
let arr = [];

console.log(typeof obj.push );  // push not on obj
console.log(typeof arr.push );  // push is on array.prototype
```

You can solve it by changing from an object literal to an array literal.

```js
let blocks = []; 

class Block {    

    constructor(X,Y,width,height){
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        blocks.push(this);
    }
}

new Block(1, 2, 3, 4);
new Block(2, 4, 6, 8);

console.log(blocks); // 3
```